# Как задать фоновое изображение div?

Tags: html, css

Не отображается фоновое изображение в div, не могу понять почему. Размеры блока указал.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header">        
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
                    <li><button type="button">Get started</button></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h1>Your strategy is only as good as you execute it.</h1>
            <button type="button">Get started</button>  
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
}

.header {
    width: 1920px;
    height: 700px;
    background-image: url(../img/header_logo.jpg);    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Фоновое изображение:
[image: Фон]

Comment: Самая распространённая ошибка - неправильный путь к картинке.

Comment: Кстати, а где в вашем коде подключение CSS файла?

Comment: О боже, и правда забыл подключить CSS :(

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно пусть к файлу указан неверно, загрузил ваш код на фидл работает, только путь взял со стака. Вероятно ошибка у вас тут: url(../img/header_logo.jpg);

https://jsfiddle.net/3zyuekdw/1/

```
.header {
    width: 1920px;
    height: 700px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwZVk.jpg) no-repeat 
center;    
    background-size: cover;
}
```